# A math parser written in Python and using infix to postfix conversion

Tags: python, math-expression-eval

Ive written this code over the course of the last days and it seems to work. However I'm not an experienced Coder so I don't know if my code is efficient enough. Any advice for improvements or nez approaches to this challenge would be very welcome.

```
def lex(task):

    def isOperator(c):
        return c in "+-*/^"

     # Push “(“onto Stack
    postfix, stack = [], ["("]
    # add “)” to the end of task
    task = task.replace(" ","") + ")"             
    # Position in task
    pos = 0                 
    # operators with precedence      
    operator = {"+": 1, "-": 1, "*": 2, "/": 2,"^": 3, "(": 0, ")": 0} 
    # Using variables to avoid IndexError
    lastTok = ""
    nextTok = ""

    while pos < len(task): 


        lastTok = task[pos - 1] if pos else ""
        current = task[pos]
        nextTok = task[pos + 1] if pos < len(task) - 1 else ""

        if current.isnumeric() or isOperator(current) and not lastTok.isnumeric() and nextTok.isnumeric(): 

            for c in task[pos + 1:]:
                if c.isnumeric() or c == ".":
                    current += c 
                    pos += 1
                else:
                    break
            # Add operands to Postfix expression        
            postfix.append(current) 
        # If left paranthesis, push to stack    
        elif current == "(":
            stack.append(current) 

        elif isOperator(current): 
            # Pop from stack top each operator with same or higher precedence
            while operator[stack[-1]]  >= operator[current]:                
                postfix.append(stack.pop())
                # Avoid out of index error
                if not stack:
                    break             
             # Add current to stack
            stack.append(current) 

        elif current == ")": 
            # Pop from stack to postfix until left paranthesis is stack top
            while stack[-1] != "(": 
                postfix.append(stack.pop())
            # Remove the left paranthesis
            del stack[-1] 

        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Illegal character at position {pos}")

        pos += 1

    return postfix


def evaluate(task):

    # Position in task
    pos = 0

    # if the task has one element its over
    while len(task) > 1:

        current = task[pos]

        if current in "+-*/^":

            # Get numbers left from operator; merge together 
            num1 = float(task[pos - 2])
            num2 = float(task[pos - 1])

            if current == "+":
                task[pos - 2:pos + 1] = [num1 + num2]

            elif current == "-":
                task[pos - 2:pos + 1] = [num1 - num2]

            elif current == "*":
                task[pos - 2:pos + 1] = [num1 * num2]

            elif current == "/":
                task[pos - 2:pos + 1] = [num1 / num2]

            elif current == "^":
                task[pos - 2:pos + 1] = [num1 ** num2]

            # List size changed, position needs to be adjusted
            pos -= 1

        else:
            # If we encounter operands we move on 
            pos += 1

    return float(task[0])


def calc(task):
    postfix = lex(task)
    return evaluate(postfix)
def lex(task):

    def isOperator(c):
        return c in "+-*/^"

     # Push “(“onto Stack
    postfix, stack = [], ["("]
    # add “)” to the end of task
    task = task.replace(" ","") + ")"             
    # Position in task
    pos = 0                 
    # operators with precedence      
    operator = {"+": 1, "-": 1, "*": 2, "/": 2,"^": 3, "(": 0, ")": 0} 
    # Using variables to avoid IndexError
    lastTok = ""
    nextTok = ""

    while pos < len(task): 


        lastTok = task[pos - 1] if pos else ""
        current = task[pos]
        nextTok = task[pos + 1] if pos < len(task) - 1 else ""

        if current.isnumeric() or isOperator(current) and not lastTok.isnumeric() and nextTok.isnumeric(): 

            for c in task[pos + 1:]:
                if c.isnumeric() or c == ".":
                    current += c 
                    pos += 1
                else:
                    break
            # Add operands to Postfix expression        
            postfix.append(current) 
        # If left paranthesis, push to stack    
        elif current == "(":
            stack.append(current) 

        elif isOperator(current): 
            # Pop from stack top each operator with same or higher precedence
            while operator[stack[-1]]  >= operator[current]:                
                postfix.append(stack.pop())
                # Avoid out of index error
                if not stack:
                    break             
             # Add current to stack
            stack.append(current) 

        elif current == ")": 
            # Pop from stack to postfix until left paranthesis is stack top
            while stack[-1] != "(": 
                postfix.append(stack.pop())
            # Remove the left paranthesis
            del stack[-1] 

        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Illegal character at position {pos}")

        pos += 1

    return postfix


def evaluate(task):

    # Position in task
    pos = 0

    # if the task has one element its over
    while len(task) > 1:

        current = task[pos]

        if current in "+-*/^":

            # Get numbers left from operator; merge together 
            num1 = float(task[pos - 2])
            num2 = float(task[pos - 1])

            if current == "+":
                task[pos - 2:pos + 1] = [num1 + num2]

            elif current == "-":
                task[pos - 2:pos + 1] = [num1 - num2]

            elif current == "*":
                task[pos - 2:pos + 1] = [num1 * num2]

            elif current == "/":
                task[pos - 2:pos + 1] = [num1 / num2]

            elif current == "^":
                task[pos - 2:pos + 1] = [num1 ** num2]

            # List size changed, position needs to be adjusted
            pos -= 1

        else:
            # If we encounter operands we move on 
            pos += 1

    return float(task[0])


def calc(task):
    postfix = lex(task)
    return evaluate(postfix)
```